# NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined

Tags: python, virtualenv, pickle, streamlit

I'm trying to create a .pkl file with hashed pswds for a login form for my streamlit app, when I run this code though the terminal tells me pickle isn't defined, I don't understand why since it should be already installed correctly.

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit_authenticator as stauth

names = ['Admin']
usernames = ['Admin']
passwords = ['xxx']

hashed_passwords = stauth.Hasher(passwords).generate()

file_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'hashed_pw.pkl'
with file_path.open('wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(hashed_passwords, file)
```

This is the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined
```

I have checked in the libraries installed in my env (base) (i only ever used this one since I'm a newb)
In the list (alphabetically ordered) I only found these two:

```
pickle-mixin              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
```

It's strange because I heard that pickle should come preinstalled, pickled-mixin is what I tried to install myself but even if I try to import it it gives me a similiar error:

```
import pickle_mixin
```

Could it be a problem with my evn?
I'm using the Python Env Manager from Don Jaymanne and it only displays (base) which is the only env I ever used up until now (I'm a newb).
when I click to activate that env and open it in the terminal it gets correctly displayed in the right corner as a terminal as 'Python base'
but still there's another terminal running, just named 'Python' in which the env won't activate, even if I input the line to activate it.
They are both Powelshell.
Whenever I run the code, unfortunately it runs with the 'Python'one, which can't get the env activated...

Comment: That error message could not come from the posted code. You did something else, probably interactively.

Comment: are the libraries installed correct? I'm trying to figure out if it a problem with the env/terminal or packages

Comment: That error would come from trying to access a variable named `pickle`. It should never result from `import (name of package)`, no matter what packages are or are not available to import. If you really got *exactly that error* from *exactly that code*, something VERY strange must be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was an env problem, powershell doesn't work well with conda env.
I used these lines in the prompt to be able to activate the envs

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

```
C:\Users\<my path to the anaconda3 folder>\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
```

So now I was able to run the conda activate  comands in the prompt

Still setting the Python Env Manager extension by clicking on "Set as Active Workspace Interpreter" to have the correct env run at launch (but the env isn't displayed -.-)

It's a bit messy, works but it isn't very pleasing.